# calculated field using to values column in a pivot

Tags: pivot-table

I have a pivot table

[image]

Year and Week are Rows.  Orders and Return Loaded are calculations based on sum(OrderSum) and sum(Reutilized) respectively

What I need is a third calculation based on the division of Return Loaded and Orders.  This is to show what % Reutilized represent of the total orders.  In the first case would be 14.04% (8 represent 14% of 57).

Comment: I already found a solution myself

I used a measure in power pivot and that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

That type of calculation is not possible within the pivot itself. There are two general workarounds.

1. You can setup the calculation in the underlying data in a way that lets you pull the value through to the pivot. I would need to know how that is laid out to explain further.
2. You can create an additional table where you read the values from your pivot using GetPivot() formulas and then do your calculation there. You would manually add new rows here for new weeks.